# The battle between TDD/Injection and information hiding - A possible compromise?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I just proposed the following pattern for someone else. I have used it a few times, when I wanted the ability to inject dependencies for test, but but still wanted this backdoor (somewhat) invisible to outsiders. Hence, the empty public ctor and internal ctor with the argument:

```
public class ClassThatUseInjection
{
    private readonly SomeClass _injectedClass;

    public ClassThatUseInjection(): this(new SomeClass()) {}

    internal ClassThatUseInjection(SomeClass injectedClass)
    {
        _injectedClass = injectedClass;
    }
}


public class SomeClass
{
    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was that since the empty ctor does nothing but forward with a new instance, my crime is not too bad. What do you think? Is is too smelly?

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: in what scenario are you considering DI a backdoor?

Comment: I am not degrading the value of a backdoor here :-) I love injection, but sometimes injecting the obvious makes the code less readable.

Comment: Perhps you can/should say that SomeClass is also internal, instead of public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is ok. In fact, what you are doing with injecting the class is Dependency Injection and a practical use of the Open/Closed Principle.
I don't even see no harm in making that internal ctor into a public one.
My problem with this is always, that I don't want to force others to create an instance of the injected class, therefore, the default ctor. But if they want to create an instance, they can go ahead and do so.

On a related note: IMHO, you should use an interface instead of a class, otherwise, I don't see too much advantage in passing that class in the first place...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would always use an interface, but kept it out to keep the story simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

> wanted this backdoor (somewhat) invisible to outsiders

Making it `internal` successfully does that, IMO.

The down-side is that it puts your tests in the same assembly.

See also [Hide public method used to help test a .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036760) about how to hide public methods if your tests are in an external assembly.

---

Edit: what you've done is especially appropriate, if `SomeClass` is logically internal ... if it's an implementation detail which shouldn't/needn't be exposed in the assembly's public interface.

Comment: The tests can be in a separate assembly, see [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's called "poor man's dependency injection", if you can't get a proper IOC container into your app its a reasonable alternative although you would be better off with the power a container gives you.

Jimmy Bogard has a good write up [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/20/the-religion-of-dependency-injection.aspx)

Comment: I don't think [that](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/20/the-religion-of-dependency-injection.aspx) is a 'good' write-up because it's one-sided. It doesn't mention the down-side, which is that it exposes (instead of 'hiding' or 'encapsulating') the existence of `IDinnerRepository` in the public API, even when `IDinnerRepository` might be an implementation detail (a private or internal data member) which most users of the public API don't want to know about.

Comment: @ChrisW does not mention the downside of what? It mentions the inherent problems with this type of injection. His arguement is pro ctor injection without poor man's DI for sure, but are you arguing that DI should not be used here?

Comment: Doesn't mention the down-side of what he's advocating. WHat he's advocating is a) having IDinnerRepository in the public API; and b) removing the default constructor. Removing the default constructor is less code in the class implementation, as he says, however there is a downside (which he doesn't mention): the down-side to removing the default constructor is that callers have to know about an IDinnerRepository instance, even when IDinnerRepository might be an implementation detail.